# Minimum permission required to Modify Private groups

Tags: community, administration, chatter-groups, collaborationgroup

By default only admin can see Feeds in Private Group, I need a moderator who can also see and modify Feeds in Private group but is not 'admin'. The solution [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_group_about.htm&type=5) Suggest to assign 'Modify all data' Permissions, which I think would be too much a do. What are minimum permissions to achieve the objective.

Comment: So, you want a user to be a moderator of all private groups?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes Exactly

Comment: Even a Chatter manager can post/edit message in a chatter group, we can either add a user as manager to app orivate group(manually/automated)

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar There are 10-50 moderators and we need to access private group without joining it. Just Like an admin does.